# how to add a new user account for an existing SVN-subversion server?

Tags: linux, svn, hgsubversion

I have an existing SVN server and I need to add more users to connect using subversion clients to do checkout, updates and commits. I read documents (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.auth.users) on how to adding new users to the svn server but I couldn't get a good idea.
Please somebody just help me to find out the correct way to add new users and grants privileges.

my problem is I have a SVN server with user "aaa" with administrative privileges. I need to add an another user call "bbb" with same privileges.

- Can svn commands use to create new user account after set-up the SVN Server ?
- or do I need to manually edit existing .conf file to add new users for SVN server ?

Server OS is CentOS 6.3

Comment: Are you using HTTP or the svn:// protocol to connect to the server? You linked to the svn:// protocol documentation; if it's HTTP then you probably want [this instead](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authz.perdir) depending on what you've already got configured. You'd need to tell us the existing configuration - http or svnserve, e.g. the non-sensitive parts of the httpd and svnaccess configuration - if you need more specific help, but chances are what you need is in those documents.

Comment: @Rup, I am using HTTP to connect to the server (url is starting with http). server computer also located in the same network.

Comment: OK, in that case you're probably running Apache on that server. You should find the mod_dav_svn module section of your Apache configuration, probably in /etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf. Look for lines like AuthType, AuthBasicProvider (if authtype basic), and AuthzSVNAccessFile if you have per-directory permissions set up. CentOS 6.3 looks like it has Subversion 1.6.11 so here's the documentation you need to understand that: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authn

Comment: @Rup, As instructed I followed the doc and finally able to add new users with htpasswd. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Rup explained in the comments. I found /etc/svn-auth-conf and list all existing users. Then added a new user using below

```
htpasswd -m /etc/svn-auth-conf <userName>
```

then new password, and password confirmation are prompted.
its worked.